# CMakeList about MySQL Connector c++ 8.0 Configuration

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

i am not good at english,
Please forgive me for the syntax error.
i want to make a mysql project in linux/windows by cmake,so i use visual studio to edit.
And i create a cmake project in visual studio,
first,i only test boost in my project ,it's run successfully.

```
find_package(Boost
            )
if (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "find Boost:\"${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}\",ENABLE_BOOST is opened")
    message(STATUS "find Boost:\"${Boost_LIBRARIES}\"")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (Boost_FOUND)
```

i can run a test by filesystem,so i want to set mysql connector c++ 8.0

```
include_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-8.0.18-winx64/lib")
add_executable (test "test.cpp")
target_link_libraries(test mysqlcppconn.dll libmysql.dll)
```

and i copy libmysql.dll and mysqlcppconn.lib(i can't find mysqlcppconn.dll,but i can use visual studio by a normal project run successfully through mysqlcppconn.lib)
to my cmake project with test.cpp

so i run code,but a error show 
**0x00007FFEE1DBE710 (ucrtbased.dll),Access violation reading location** in xstring.insert.h(a ms .h? i don't know this header)

there are my code,and i run successfully by a normal project through vs2017,but cmake can not run.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello CMake。" << endl;
    cout << "You Finished." << endl;
    string exepath = boost::filesystem::initial_path<boost::filesystem::path>().string();
    cout << exepath << endl;
    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        cout << "create success" << endl;
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "123");
        con->setSchema("test");
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("select * from detect");
        cout << "search..."<<endl;
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "searhing..username:" << endl;
            cout << res->getString("username") << endl;
            cout << "searhing..password:" << endl;
            cout << res->getString("password") << endl;
        }

        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException&e) {
        cout << "#ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line" << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "#ERR:" << e.what();
        cout << "(MySQL error code:" << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ",SQLState:" << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;
        cout << "link failed" << endl;

    }
return 0;
}
```

I debug code,and it's error in

```
cout << res->getString("username") << endl;
```

i promise my tables is ok

and i run code successfully by mysql c api through visual studio cmake project,but mysql connector c++ can not.

if you can tell me what shoud i do,
thank you very much!

Update:
@Alex 
i run the code ,then visual studio auto go the xstring_insert.h

```
// xstring_insert.h internal header
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
            && _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputn(_Data, (streamsize)_Size)
                != (streamsize)_Size)
                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
```

my error is happend in if().
And visual studio output is

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEF776E710 (ucrtbased.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

@seccpur
I add .c_str() in my cout code,and i run successfully,could you tell my why i need do this.And i don't use .c_str() that can run code successfully in my general windows console.

Comment: What do you mean, `(a ms .h? i don't know this header)`?  Is this a part of the error message?  Please update your post to make it clear.

Comment: Try `std::cout << res->getString("username").c_str();`

Comment: i updated my post in questions,and i run code successfully with add .c_str(). Could you like tell my why need add .c_str() in my code? @Alex

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory.  It says:

```
Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

In other words, you are trying to read address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (= -1), but you do not have permission to read it.

Let us now look at your `if` statement, since you′ve figured out that′s where the problem is.

```
if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
        && _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputn(_Data, (streamsize)_Size)
            != (streamsize)_Size)
```

Let us see which of these parts can cause that error: in

```
_State == ios_base::goodbit
```

you′re comparing one object to another.  No such error should appear.  In

```
    && _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputn(_Data, (streamsize)_Size)
```

you′re following the pointer of `_Ostr.rdbuf()`.  If this value is -1, then it would cause the error you′ve quoted.

Finally, the last line, you′re again comparing two values, so that error is not possible.  Now you know what the culprit of this error is.  So the library in question would need to make sure that `_Ostr.rdbuf()` is a valid value before attempting to follow its pointer: apparently not all libraries do.

On the other hand, `cstring()` takes the value and converts it to a string, even if it is NOT valid.  This is why using it works in this case.

Good job at improving your question.  The initial question sounded terrible.

Comment: xstring_insert.h is not my edit code,I think it's complie auto add standard code, I means that my cmakelist.txt edit error or my main.cpp code error? So should I care about mysql connector cmakelist.txt or I care about my code how to getstring() from mysql?

Comment: I'm aware of that (that's why I said "*the library* ... would need to ...").  I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but I believe the second part is what you need to care about.